# model control flow instruction using basic arithmetic operators

Tags: computer-science

Is it possible to model control flow instruction using only basic operators (`+`,`-`, `/`, `*`)? If no, what is the minimal set of operators to model it?

What would be equivalent impementation of it:

`def iff(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int): Int = if (a < 0) b else c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a theoretical point of view [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) is Turing complete.
However PA is a first order system, while  the "basic operators" you gave are not even formalized and cannot be considered part of PA.

*So you are not probably asking about PA and similar system.*

If you "allows" primitive recursion, you gain access to the [Primitive recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function). These can be extended to works with integers (and not just natural numbers).
While they are not Turing complete they are powerful enough to compute the function you gave (see below) and thus to make decisions.
Note however that the recursion is achieved through [structural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) on the natural numbers, with the base case (the function computed on "zero") being essentially a form of specialization (i.e. and *if*).

*So you are not probable asking about PRF either.*

If the "basic operators" means expressions, in the programming languages sense, involving only the operations listen then the answer is no (unless `b` = `c`).
This can be proven by noting that the basic operators are continue, while `iif` is generally not (being discontinued in 0).

However if the programming language has pattern matching then `iif` can be implemented analogously as how it is done with PRF.
If the integers have finite precision, one can exploit a suitable encoding of them (like [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)) to extract the "sign information" and to implement the `sgn(a)` function and thus `iif` (see below).

---

The subsequent question asking for a minimal set of operators is poorly posed, because it lacks context: what "control" are we trying to flow? In other words what computational model are we using?

If we can abstract, encode and manipulate a computation, like a function, for example with pointer to functions, first order functions or continuation (or self modify code), than we can make an array with the two branches of an *if* and index into it with `iif`

```
var branches = [() => console.log('a not equals b'), () => console.log('a equals b')];

var a = ...
var b = ...

branches[iif(a-b, 0, iif(b-a, 0, 1))]();
```

This computational model may or may not be what you had in mind when you asked your question.
Without an abstraction of computation, but still assuming the presence of `iif`, we can do specialization but not (even bounded) iteration (unless we can do arithmetic on the Program Counter).
So we also need an operator that apply an expression, dependent on a variable *x*, a fixed number of time, incrementing *x* each time.
But this is just a crude primitive recursion, and our model is becoming very similar to the PRF.

Finally, in general you need a potentially unbounded (endless) iteration, like [μ-minimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function).

However we have shown that we cannot implement `iif` in an abstract programming language with arithmetic expression only.
I conjecture that introduction a discontinuous function like (like `sgn`, the sign function) would suffice for implementing `iif`.

---

Writing `iif` in terms of primitive recursive function `sgn`.

Here we abuse the notation by using the arithmetic operators inline, and by implicitly using their extended version that work with the integers under a suitable encoding.

Using the PRF `iff` can be defined as `(b + c - sgn'(a) * (b - c))/2` where
`sgn'(a)` is a function that return -1 if *a* is negative, 1 otherwise.
It can be computed from `sgn(a)` (the standard sign function) as `sgn'(a) = (sgn(a) + 2) / 2 * 2 - 1`.
Note that division is between integers, so `x / 2 * 2` doesn't cancel out.
The `sgn(a)` can be computed as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Some_common_primitive_recursive_functions).

Comment: It's excelent answer. It is more than I expected. Sorry for not being precise and not provide formalized way of defining operators. Probably if I knew whether define operators as PA or PRF I would be able to google these terms and find solution by my self. That's why question is so general.